# Begineer's sorting with tuples

Tags: python, python-2.7

How would I start sorting this list so that it displays the names of the countries in order, determined by the conversion rate (it involves reading data from a text file)?

```
America,Dollar,1
Argentina,Peso,8.257
Australia,Dollar,1.432
Austria,Euro,0.82
```

I have a general idea about how to start, but I don't know what to do from here. Here's what I have so far:

```
fhand = open('Exchange.txt')
for line in fhand:
    line = line.split(',')
print line[0], line[2]
```

Edit: I want it to display only the name of the countries, and not the exchange rate.  Additionally, i'm a novice, so the simpler answer the more helpful and the better I can understand/learn. The outputs should be something like:

```
Austria
Australia
America
Argentina
```

Comment: read it into a dataframe and then sort the dataframe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't mind a multi-dimensional list as the result, here's a relatively short way to do it.

Exchange.txt:

```
America,Dollar,1
Argentina,Peso,8.257
Australia,Dollar,1.432
Austria,Euro,0.82
```

Code:

```
with open('Exchange.txt') as f:
    lines = [x.strip().split(",") for x in f.readlines()]
    #reverse = True for descending sorted order
    lines.sort(key=lambda x: float(x[-1]), reverse=True)
    print(lines)
```

Result:

```
[['Argentina', 'Peso', '8.257'], ['Australia', 'Dollar', '1.432'], 
 ['America', 'Dollar', '1'], ['Austria', 'Euro', '0.82']]
```

Without `reverse=True` (increasing order)

```
[['Austria', 'Euro', '0.82'], ['America', 'Dollar', '1'], 
 ['Australia', 'Dollar', '1.432'], ['Argentina', 'Peso', '8.257']]
```

Comment: What would be the best way to only have the countries print instead of the country, unit, and exchange rate?

Answer (score 2):

So first you want to read your data into a single list of tuples (or any sequence, but it's better to use tuples because you know the size), as shown below. Note that I use the `with open() as f` construct to automatically close the file after we are done reading it:

```
data = []
with open('Exchange.txt') as fhand:
    for line in fhand:
        data.append(line.split(','))
```

Now, we want to sort this using the [built-in sorting functions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted):

```
data.sort(key = lambda item: float(item[-1]))
```

With all of this put together, and a slight simplification using [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map):

```
with open('Exchange.txt') as fhand:
    data = map(lambda line: line.split(','), fhand)
data.sort(key = lambda item: float(item[-1]))
```

Answer (score 1):

it might be pretty easy if you can use pandas module:

```
import pandas as pd

fn = r'D:\temp\.data\36961029.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(fn, header=None, names=['country','cur','rate']).sort_values(by='rate')

# print sorted
print(df)

# save sorted DF to new CSV
df.to_csv('sorted_data.csv', index=False)
```

Output:

```
     country     cur   rate
3    Austria    Euro  0.820
0    America  Dollar  1.000
2  Australia  Dollar  1.432
1  Argentina    Peso  8.257
```

sorted_data.csv:

```
country,cur,rate
Austria,Euro,0.82
America,Dollar,1.0
Australia,Dollar,1.432
Argentina,Peso,8.257
```